# Phonegap android apk cannot be uploaded

Tags: android, phonegap-desktop-app

I get the following error while I try to upload apk to publish in the playstore.

"You need to use a different package name because "com.phonegap.www" already exists in Google Play."

While creating the app in Phonegap-desktop I've given a different package name(com.phonegap.nv.appname). Tried a couple of other names too.  And for the same issue somebody suggested to change the package name at App>Settings>Configuration inside phonegap build website. But the Configuration section is empty. What am I doing wrong? I'm building the release app using the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically just change the android:package attribute in your manifest, and then refactor your src/ folders to follow that same package name.

As an alternative you can use the rename option in Eclipse, but it will have to modify all of the R.class imports in any of your java files that use resources. This will look a little intimidating, but should work fine.

Comment: I don't use eclipse. I use phonegap desktop to create app and  phonegap website to build it. So I don't know where can I find it.